# Recursive Component returning property undefined error in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently completing a frontend mentor challenge that involves building an interactive comment section. In this project, I want the users to be able to reply to each other continuously, and hence I have used a recursive component.

I am going to be pasting the code for the two offending components

Here is my code for the Comment component

```jsx
// Comment.jsx
import { useEffect } from "react";
import ReplySection from "./ReplySection";

const Comment =({content, upvotes,image,username, isUser, replies, replyMethod, createdAt, id,upvoteMethod})=> {
   useEffect(()=> {
       console.log(replies)
   })
    return(
        
        <div className="comment-container" key = {id}>
            <div className="comment">
                <div className="upvotes-section">
                    <div className="upvotes">
                        <img id="upvote" src="/images/icon-plus.svg" onClick={()=> {
                            upvoteMethod(id, "upvote")
                        }}></img>
                        <h3>{upvotes}</h3>
                        <img id="downvote" src="/images/icon-minus.svg" onClick={()=> {
                            upvoteMethod(id, "downvote")

                        }}></img>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="comment-side">
                    <div className="comment-header">
                        <div className="profile">
                            <img src={image}></img>
                            <h5>{username}</h5>
                            <h6 className="created-at">{createdAt}</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div className="options">
                            <img src={isUser ? "images/icon-delete.svg" : ""}></img>
                            <img src="/images/icon-reply.svg" onClick={()=> {
                                replyMethod(id)
                            }}></img>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="comment-content">
                        <h5>{content}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            </div>

            <ReplySection reply={replies} replyMethod={replyMethod} upvoteMethod={upvoteMethod}></ReplySection>

          
        </div>
    )

}

export default Comment;
```

and here is the Reply Section, where all the replies for each comment are stored.

```jsx
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Comment from "./Comment";
const ReplySection=({reply,replyMethod,upvoteMethod})=> {
    return(
        <div className="reply-section">
           {reply.map(el=> {
               return(
                 <Comment content = {el.content} upvotes={el.score} id={el.id} upvoteMethod = {upvoteMethod} image = {el.user.image.png} username = {el.user.username} replyMethod = {replyMethod} replies = {el.replies} createdAt={el.createdAt} isUser={ el.user.username === "juliusomo"? true :false} key={el.id}></Comment>
                  
               )
           })}
        </div>
    )

}

export default ReplySection;
```

and here is my App jsx file, where the object and methods I pass down are located.

```
import Comment from './components/Comment';
import './App.css';
import CommentArea from './components/CommentArea';
import TextField from './components/TextField';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  let date = new Date()
  let displayedComments = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "content": "Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved. But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.",
      "createdAt": "1 month ago",
      "score": 12,
      "user": {
        "image": { 
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png",
          "webp": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.webp"
        },
        "username": "amyrobson"
      },
      "replies": []
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "content": "Woah, your project looks awesome! How long have you been coding for? I'm still new, but think I want to dive into React as well soon. Perhaps you can give me an insight on where I can learn React? Thanks!",
      "createdAt": "2 weeks ago",
      "score": 5,
      "user": {
        "image": { 
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png",
          "webp": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.webp"
        },
        "username": "maxblagun"
      },
      "replies": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "content": "If you're still new, I'd recommend focusing on the fundamentals of HTML, CSS, and JS before considering React. It's very tempting to jump ahead but lay a solid foundation first.",
          "createdAt": "1 week ago",
          "score": 4,
          "replyingTo": "maxblagun",
          "user": {
            "image": { 
              "png": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.png",
              "webp": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.webp"
            },
            "username": "ramsesmiron"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "content": "I couldn't agree more with this. Everything moves so fast and it always seems like everyone knows the newest library/framework. But the fundamentals are what stay constant.",
          "createdAt": "2 days ago",
          "score": 2,
          "replyingTo": "ramsesmiron",
          "user": {
            "image": { 
              "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
              "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
            },
            "username": "juliusomo"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]


  const [comments,setComment] = useState(displayedComments);

  const upvotePost=(id, action)=> {

    let counter = 0
    action==="upvote"? counter++ : counter--;

    if (Math.abs(counter) <= 1) {
      const mult = action === "upvote" ? 1 : -1;
      setComment(
         comments => comments.map((comment) =>comment.id === id
          ? {...comment, score: comment.score + (1*mult)}
          : comment
        )
      ); 
    }  
    console.log(counter)  
  }
   
  
  
  const dateToMonth=(month)=> {
    const months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]

    return months[month]
  }
  const newComment=()=> {
    let comment = document.querySelector(".text-area")
    if (comment.value !="") {
      setComment([...comments, {"id":Math.random()*100000,
      "content":comment.value,
      "createdAt": `${dateToMonth(date.getMonth())}`,
      "score": 0,
      "user": {
        "image": { 
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
          "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
        },
        "username": "juliusomo"
      },
      "replies": []}])
    }
   

  } 

  const newReply=(id)=> {
    let commentClone = [...comments]
    for (let i =0; i<commentClone.length; i++) {
      if (commentClone[i].id == id) {
        commentClone[i].replies.push({
          "id": Math.random() * 10000,
          "content": "I couldn't agree more with this. Everything moves so fast and it always seems like everyone knows the newest library/framework. But the fundamentals are what stay constant.",
          "createdAt": "2 days ago",
          "score": 2,
          "replyingTo": "ramsesmiron",
          "user": {
            "image": { 
              "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
              "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
            },
            "username": "juliusomo"
          }
        })
        setComment(commentClone)
      }
    } 
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CommentArea  replyMethod = {newReply} upvoteMethod ={upvotePost} comments={comments}></CommentArea>
      <TextField commentMethod={newComment}></TextField>
       
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when I open live server, I ended up getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at ReplySection (ReplySection.jsx:5:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16398:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:21144:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22634:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27597:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26733:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26642:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26611:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:26020:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26264:1)
```

strangely enough, when I console log the replies array in my Comment component, it just shows an array, nothing out of the ordinary.

I am stumped on this problem and would like to know what's going on. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like `el.replies` sometimes doesn't exist? Don't log in an effect hook, log in the component block itself

Comment: @CertainPerformance ive logged it in the component, it returns the appropriate array and the result is not undefined.

Comment: Your code shows you logging inside the hook, not inside the component

Comment: @CertainPerformance  sorry, i meant to say that I revised my code to log in the component and still encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Situations that would cause this are...

---

The first use of `Comment` has the `replies` state initialised as `undefined`. It might be updated later in an effect hook but until that happens, you cannot call `map()` on it.

The simple solution is to initialise your array states as arrays

```js
const [replies, setReplies] = useState([]); // empty array
```

---

Some of your nested *replies* do not have `replies` properties, ie `el.replies` is undefined.

In these cases, you can either use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to safely call `.map()`...

```jsx
{reply?.map((el) => (
  <Comment
    content={el.content}
    ... etc
  />
))}
```

or if you need more control over the layout, use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

```jsx
{reply && (
  {/* content when reply exists */}
)}
{!reply && (
  {/* content when reply does not exist */}
)}
```

Comment: the optional chaining solution worked, but can you explain to me why it gets set as undefined? in the object I pass down, all the 'replies' property are clearly set to an array.

Comment: ah sorry, I just edited the post to show the App.jsx code right after I wrote my previous reply. Can you take a look at it now?

Comment: @KevinH easy, the replies with IDs `3` and `4` have no `replies` property

Comment: well, that was stupid. Sorry, I sometimes don't pay attention to stuff like this lol

Comment: @KevinH unexpected data is how we build fault tolerant software 